# SQLAlchemy: hybrid property with class expression across multiple relationships

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm interested in figuring out how to write a `@expression` for the  `@hybrid_property` below.

The schema is a little complex since this is a small part of a much larger project, over which I don't have total control, so please don't get hung up on the odd arrangement of classes and table definitions and the use of both relationships and mappers.   I've have also had to change all the class names in order to post this here, so please forgive any minor typos.   Here are the relevant portions:

**tables.py**

```
course_table = Table('course', metadata,
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True),
    name = Column(String(80)),
    )

book_table = Table('book', metadata,
    booknum = Column(Integer, primary_key=True),
    title = Column(String(80)),
    )

librarybook = Table('librarybook', metadata,
    dewey_num = Column(Integer, primary_key=True),
    booknum = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('book.booknum')),
    shelf_location = Column(String(80)),
    )


author = Table('author', metadata,
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True),
    name = Column(String(80)),
    )

course_book_view_table = view('course_book_view', metadata,
    Column('course_id', Integer,
               ForeignKey(course_table.c.id),
               primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
        Column('booknum', Text,
               ForeignKey(book_table.c.booknum),
               primary_key=True),
    )
)
```

**model.py**

```
import tables as t


class Course(Base):
    course_books=relation(Book,
                              secondary=t.course_book_view_table,
                              backref='courses',
                              order_by=Book.dewey,
                              ),

    @hybrid_property
    def course_book_author_names(self):
          if self.course_books:
              return list(set([lb.author.name
                  for b in self.course_books
                  for lb in b.library_books]))
          else:
              return None


    @course_book_author_names.expression
    def course_book_author_names(cls):
        join_tbl = t.course_book_view_table.join(
            t.librarybook,
            t.librarybook.c.booknum == t.course_book_view_table.c.booknum) \
            .join(
                t.author,
                    t.author.c.booknum == t.librarybook.c.booknum
            )
        q = select([func.array_agg(t.author.c.name)])
        q = q.select_from(join_tbl)
        q = q.where(t.course_book_view_table.c.course_id == cls.id)
        q = q.distinct()
        return q.label('course_book_author_names')

class Book(Base):
    pass

class Librarybook(Base):
    pass

class Author(Base):
    pass


mapper(Librarybook, t.librarybook, properties=dict(
    book = relationship(
        Book,
        primaryjoin=t.librarybook.c.booknum == t.book_table.c.booknum,
        foreign_keys=[t.librarybook.c.booknum],
        backref='library_books',
    ),
    author=relationship(Author, backref='books'),
))

mapper(Author, t.author)
```

I would eventually be able to use the `@hybrid_property` in two ways:

as a python property:

```
>>>course = session.query(Course).get(1234)
>>>course.course_book_author_names
['Bjarne Stroustrup', 'Brian Kernighan', 'Dennis Ritchie', 'Guido van Rossum', 'James Gosling']
```

and as a class level expression for use with SA, something along the lines of:

```
>>>session.query(Course).filter(Course.course_book_author_names \
.any(Author.name == 'Bjarne Stroustrup')).first()
1234
```

Rather, I get an error:

```
session.query(Course).filter(Course.course_book_author_names \
.any(Author.name == 'Bjarne Stroustrup')).first()
...
AttributeError: Neither 'Label' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'any'
```

I'm not 100% sure that this is the right way to call it, and I'm open to suggestions for better syntax (in_ instead of any?) that would produce the right filtering effect.

On the other hand, maybe I just need some kind of custom relationship that more directly connects courses to authors?

For what it's worth, the underlying database is postgres.

Any thoughts or insights appreciated!